# Pytest fixture structure

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a big API to test with pytest. Alot of the tests have different parameters so im using `@mark.parametrize("username, password", [(Correctuser, Correctpassword), (Correctuser, ""), ...]`

I have a mock database where i can insert data. I use fixtures for this. I want to validate my tests with the data i put in the db so that the tests can be done somewhat dynamically.

```
#conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def user_data():
#do db setup
user = (username=Test123, Password=TestPassword)
db.add(user)
yield user # <--- use this in tests to validate
#cleanup
```

The problem is if i make a post request i dont want my fixture to insert data because of duplication. Im struggling to know how i should structure the fixtures. Is it possible to have the database fixtures in my conftest.py file, antoher file with data fixtures (which is sent to db for insertion and tests for validation) and a file with parameter fixtures?

I've tried sending the validation data directly to the tests but i cant get lazy_parametrization to work.